# NSGenericException when trying to remove an object from an array in iOS

Tags: ios, exception, enumerator

I have checked the examples of how to fix this problem but I am still facing it..

My Code is

```
NSEnumerator *enu= [obstacles objectEnumerator];
    NSMutableArray *delete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Object *obj;
    while ((obj=[enu nextObject])!=nil)
    {

        if ([obj isKindOfClass: [BObject class]] &&  CGPointEqualToPoint(obj.position, point)    ) {
            [view.objects removeObject: obj];
            //[obstacles removeObject: obj]; 
            [delete addObject:obj];
            }
    }


    [obstacles removeObjectsInArray:delete];
    [delete release];
```

the error is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x6a97ba0> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

Update: My code work if there is only one object in my `obstacles` array. it fails with multiple objects..

Comment: NSMutablaArray.. it doesn't cause the error.. I get the same error even if I comment it out..

Comment: the error is basically saying you're deleting from an array that is in an enumeration loop. Have you stepped each line thru the debugger to see which line causes it to fail?

Comment: yes.. `[obstacles removeObjectsInArray:delete];` causes the error but it's out of the enumeration.. so I am not sure..

Comment: Can you the pointers to obstacles and view.objects, respectively?

Comment: Sorry, I left out a word! Could you print the objects `obstacles` and `view.objects` and see what their memory addresses are? I suspect they may be the same object! Also - try instantiating `delete` with `[NSMutableArray array]` instead of `alloc...init` (and drop the `release` at the end of this code block..)

Comment: Oh and nevermind about my `NSMutableArray` comment I was thinking of something else...